# Assing multiple values to one variable - shell

Tags: powershell

I have a code running at the moment that pulls data from a txt file . But  I decided not to take all the values from a separate list,i want to implement these values direct into the code

```
$SERVERS = gc "C:\Users\listofSERVERS.TXT "
```

Rather have all values in the code

```
$SERVERS =( echo "Server1, Server2, Server3 ..." )
```

But the code is returning an empty file. Not sure if I am assigning $SERVERS variable correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array of servers you can use something like the below. Note that it will only print out the current server to the console :)

```
$servers = @("Server1","Server2","Server3")
Foreach($server in $servers){
    Write-Host $server
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The doublequotes make it a single string.  It could be as simple as:

```
$SERVERS = echo Server1 Server2 Server3
```